# How to make kile to accept absolute pathnames at inverse search?

Tags: kile, forward-inverse-search

I have the combination Kile and SumatraPDF under Windows 7. The inverse search is running so far. The main problem is, that if I activate it, Kile opens the file in a new tab under the absolute path name instead of selecting the already open tab from the project. That's annoying as I get twice as much tabs and they are not linked to the project.

Is there a possibility to

- call Kile with a relative path or
- make Kile open first the project file?

My command within Sumatra is th following:

```js
C:\ProgramData\KDE\bin\kile.exe %f --line %l
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for Kile, which we cannot really hope to provide as an answer.